PayFort always return Signature mismatch error for apple on web
We are integrating Apple Pay On Web and doing the payment process via PayFort.
We are successfully able to get the Apple Pay session and when we pass the necessary to payfort sandbox endpoint.

At first we are trying to generate the hashing, where we followed the same whatever mentioned in API Documentation on PayFort. But still we are getting a same error "Signature Mismatch"

Here is my code,
                "digital_wallet":"APPLE_PAY",
                "command":"PURCHASE",
                "access_code": process.env.access_code,
                "merchant_identifier": process.env.merchant_identifier,
                "merchant_reference": "Test " + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10),
                "amount": (parseFloat(payload.amount) * 100).toString(),
                "currency": payload.currency,
                "language":"en",
                "customer_email":"test@example.com",
                "apple_data": payload.paymentData.data,
                "apple_signature": payload.paymentData.signature,
                "apple_header": {
                    "apple_transactionId": payload.paymentData.header.transactionId,
                    "apple_ephemeralPublicKey": payload.paymentData.header.ephemeralPublicKey,
                    "apple_publicKeyHash": payload.paymentData.header.publicKeyHash
                },
                "apple_paymentMethod":{
                    "apple_displayName": payload.paymentMethod.displayName,
                    "apple_network": payload.paymentMethod.network,
                    "apple_type": payload.paymentMethod.type
                },
                "signature": ""
            };

            let payload_signature = await new crypto_helper().calculate(options, process.env.sha_request_phrase, "sha256");
            
            options.signature =  payload_signature;
            console.log("options", options)

            const response = await axios.post('https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi', options, {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });

async calculate(unsorted_dict, sha_phrase, sha_method = 'sha256') {
        const sorted_keys = Object.keys(unsorted_dict).sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase()));
        const sorted_dict = sorted_keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
            acc[key] = unsorted_dict[key];
            return acc;
        }, {});

        // const result = Object.entries(sorted_dict).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`).join('');

        let result = '';

        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(sorted_dict)) {
            if (key === 'signature') {
                continue;
            }
            if (typeof val !== 'object') {
                result += `${key}=${val}`;
            } else {
                let sub_str = `${key}={`;
                let index = 0;
                const keys = Object.keys(val).sort();
                for (const k of keys) {
                    sub_str += `${k}=${val[k]}`;
                    if (index < keys.length - 1) {
                        sub_str += ', ';
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                sub_str += '}';
                result += sub_str;
            }
        }

        const result_string = `${sha_phrase}${result}${sha_phrase}`;
        console.log(result);

        const signature = crypto.createHash(sha_method).update(result_string).digest('hex');
        return signature;
    }

